# How to do this Observable correctly?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a part of code:

```
id$!: Observable<string | null>;
```

and I need to rewrite this to Observable for using this method:

```
getCharacterDetail() { 
   if (!this.id$) {
     return;
   }
   this.store$.dispatch(getCharDetailsData({id: this.id$ }));

 }
```

Comment: You could do `id$.subscribe(subjectInstance$)` but it depends on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73479097/how-to-rewrite-observable-to-behaviorsubject

Answer (score 0):

```
id!: string;
```

for url parameter no need to use observables.

```
this.id = this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

and use it in getCharacterDetail.

```
getCharacterDetail() { 
   if (!this.id) {
     return;
   }
   this.store$.dispatch(getCharDetailsData({id: this.id }));

 }
```

but if you persist to change that:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.router.paramMap.subscribe((res: any) => {
     this.id = res.id;
     this.getCharacterDetail();
     this.characterDetail$ = this.store$.select(charDetailsSelector);
    });
}
```

UPDATE:

if you need id as observable:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.id$ = this.router.paramMap.pipe(params => params.id);
  // or this.id$ = of(this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
  this.id$.subscribe(id => {
     if (!id) {
      return;
     }
     this.getCharacterDetail(id);
});
  
    
}

getCharacterDetail(id) { 
  this.store$.dispatch(getCharDetailsData({id: id}));
  this.characterDetail$ = this.store$.select(charDetailsSelector);
}
```

Comment: you can pass id to its function. updated again